# Error: Invalid Type

Tags: apex, compile-error, wrapper-class, invalid

What is it I am doing to get the invalid type error?

```
    public with sharing class MyController {

        public list<JSONWrapper> wrapper {get;set;}
        public integer appTotal{get;set;}   

        public void getDeserialize() {

        string jsonresponse = '[{"appList":[{"dealerID":"ABC123","dealerName":"ABC Auto Dealer",                    "reportingPeriod":"2019-05-                 18","fsitCode":"FIFS","idl":"Y","casCode":"STEONE","submissionCount":2},{"dealerID":                    "ABC123","dealerName":"ABC Auto Dealer","reportingPeriod":"2019-06-27","fsitCode":"FIFS","idl":"Y",                     "casCode":"STEONE","submissionCount":5}],"eclist":                  [{"dealerID":"XL1HX","submitUserID":"BCUSER1","bookedDate":"2019-05-22                  00:00:00.0","ecEligible":"Y","caBookedCount":1,"ecBookedCount":0},{"dealerID":"XL1HX","submitUserID":                   "BCUSER1","bookedDate":"2019-06-05 00:00:00.0","ecEligible":"Y","caBookedCount":1,"ecBookedCount":                  0}]}]';

            system.debug('json string is ' +jsonresponse);
            wrapper = (list<JSONWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(jsonresponse, list<JSONWrapper>.class);

            system.debug('This is the wrapper' +wrapper);

        }

        public integer getTotalAppCount(list<JSONWrapper> wrapper) {

        // loop through each element in the appList, till the end of the list.
        // get grand total of submissionCount
        // return grand total

            for(JSONWrapper jw: wrapper){
                jw.appTotal=0;

                // Error is here
                for (ApplicationList cp : jw.appList) {
                  jw.appTotal += cp.submissionCount;
                }
            }

            return appTotal;
        }

}




public class JSONWrapper {

    public List<ApplicationList> appList{get;set;}
    public List<ElectronicContractList> eclist {get;set;}
    public integer appTotal {get;set;} 

    public class ElectronicContractList{
        public String  dealerID{get;set;}
        public String submitUserID{get;set;}
        public String bookedDate{get;set;}
        public String ecEligible{get;set;}
        public Integer caBookedCount{get;set;}
        public Integer ecBookedCount{get;set;}
    }

    public class ApplicationList {
        public String dealerID{get;set;}
        public String dealerName{get;set;}
        public String reportingPeriod{get;set;}
        public String fsitCode{get;set;}
        public String idl{get;set;}
        public String casCode{get;set;}
        public Integer submissionCount{get;set;}
    }
}
```

> Error: Invalid Type:ApplicationList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ApplicationList` is an inner class of `JSONWrapper`. References to that class outside of the `JSONWrapper` class itself, where it's in scope, must qualify the name with its outer class: `JSONWrapper.ApplicationList`. Hence,

```
for (JSONWrapper.ApplicationList cp : jw.appList) {
```